# requiring a dir instead of a file?

Tags: php

I got this php error message:

```
Warning: require(/home/victor/public_html/plugindev/wp-includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: Not a directory in /home/victor/public_html/plugindev/wp-settings.php on line 75

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/victor/public_html/plugindev/wp-includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/victor/public_html/plugindev/wp-settings.php on line 75
```

but...:

```
 ~  stat /home/victor/public_html/plugindev/wp-includes/plugin.php 
File: ‘/home/victor/public_html/plugindev/wp-includes/plugin.php’
➜  ~  stat /home/victor/public_html/plugindev/wp-settings.php
File: ‘/home/victor/public_html/plugindev/wp-settings.php’
```

and the most strange part, the occurs randomly and at randomly files and all exists. (ie already seen the same error for other files)

I think is is a incompatiblity with plugin I'm developing but doesn't know how to debug

Comment: More likely then not the issue is that the user running the web server does not have permission to access the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is clearly a permissions problem here.

```
<?php
$dir = '/path/to/dir';
$file = $dir . '/file.ext';

echo is_readable($dir)
    ? "Dir is readable"
    : "Dir is not readable";

echo is_readable($file)
    ? "File is readable"
    : "File is not readable";
```

That snippet of code will tell you if there is a permissions issue and you can resolve the code appropriately. If it is 'random' then its possible that you are expecting files to be present when they have not been generated yet? If that is the case, the checking code above can be used to dictate if a file needs to be created.

Comment: You are right! replaced dir and file and the result is: Dir is readableFile is not readable; so thank you!